# Как отлавливать warning в PHP?

Tags: php

Есть код, который отрабатывает ответы на запросы к API и там есть такой участок:

```
if(count($temp['data']) > 0) {
```

Который раз в 2-3 тысячи запросов сбоит. Видимо, от API приходит какой-то не задокументарованный ответ. Получается ошибка:

> PHP Warning:  count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Для этого я поставил `try catch` в надежде отловить ответ, приходящий от сервера:

```
try {
    $isCountable = count($temp['data']) > 0;
} catch(Exception $e) {
    error_log('UNCOUNTABLE ERROR! At ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . ' with data:\n' . json_encode($temp));
}
```

Но catch просто не срабатывает в момент появления ошибки, а в консоли выводится всё тот же warning на строке: `$isCountable = count($temp['data']) > 0;`

Как мне отловить этот варнинг?

Comment: `if (is_array($temp['data']) && count($temp['data']) > 0) {...}`

Answer (score 0):

Вам в ошибке уже описали что надо проверить:

```
if (is_array($temp['data']) || ($temp['data'] instanceof Countable)) {
    // correct
} else {
    // incorrect
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Поставил в else вывод в лог и там стал появляться такой json: `{"success":true,"data":[],"error":null,"currency":"rub"}`. Но почему он не является `instanceof Countable`? `count()` должен возвращать просто 0.

Comment: По этому джсону вроде все нормально должно быть. А если в лог фиксировать собственно содержимое `$temp['data']`, а не весь джсон?

Comment: Дело в том, что `instanceof Countable` - это не то же самое, что и `is_array()`. Почему-то даже если массив не пуст, то он всё равно считается не `Countable`. Сейчас оставил одно лишь условие с `is_array()`. Жду пока. Ещё не было плохих ответов от сервера.

Comment: Я поэтому и написал две проверки.